# Call a number from an Android application without using native action call Intent?

Tags: android, phone-call

Is it possible to call a number from an Android application, without using native action call Intent?

That means without using code like below:

```
  Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
  phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:91-800-001-0101"));
  startActivity(phoneIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Working on standard Android SDK, that is the only way to start a call.

Answer (score 0):

Not from an ordinary Android SDK app. A custom ROM mod certainly could.